Disable any automatic updates during install when installing via official ISO
I've tried searching for this, but I seem to only come up with results for disabling auto upgrades "after" installation, but I want to do it "during" installation. Hopefully this isn't much of a dupe question.
Background:
The Ubuntu Server 20.04 installer will execute "downloading and installing security updates" as a final installation step.
A user can manually select "Cancel update and reboot" to cancel the process.

My goal is to:

Install Ubuntu Server via an official Ubuntu Server ISO (assume it's burned to a disk) on bare metal.
The installer will NOT auto-install any packages.
The user does not need to manually select "cancel update" during the install process.
Packages can still be installed during install if a human chooses to (ex: OpenSSH
Server).

I already have a PXE environment with cloud-init working fine for normal use-cases and it takes care of this for me. However, this question is specifically around using a base/vanilla ISO installer DVD or USB media on bare metal, without any other prep work (cloud-init baked in, or on a file server, etc).
Since there is an option to "cancel" it I really was hoping there is a way to just not start it at all right from the menu or boot options.
I'm sure I'll be asked "Why?", so here that is:
This is an ad-hoc process in a 3rd party facility that does not have management layer access to the normal pxe environment, private apt repos, or provisioning file shares (where this wouldn't be an issue). The eventual upstream inventory provisioners will be performing package management on this host with private repos. Allowing auto updates against public repos during install will introduce config drift. This is already handled for normal operations via cloud-init/pxe elsewhere but this question differs from that.

See here

HI @eyoung100 thanks for the response but I am not seeing how that applies to the installer or the context of my quesiton. That linked question seems to be around disabling updates during general operations, not during OS installation. Can you help point me how that question it applies to mine? Thanks.

I believe that if start the LiveCD/USB as "Try Ubuntu" you should be able to edit the files in the answer I linked, temporarily save them, start the installer, finish the install, and reboot.  After rebooting repeat the process on the installed system.

I think you would have to provide autoinstall configuration.  Can you plug in a USB stick with the autoinstall files that the vanilla ISO can find?

@AndrewLowther Thanks, yea that's what I feared would be the answer here. I guess I'll just disconnect network during the install or bake autoinstall into the ISO. I found that the Ubuntu installer not only pulls down security updates at the end of install it also will NOT use any files on the ISO if it has a network connection. In testing all my packages were mismatched even after cancelling the security updates. Ubuntu had offered a "legacy server" ISO that doesn't do online stuff but they ditched it on 22.04 onwards.
